Why is Grammarly no longer working with Mosaico?
I have Grammarly installed on my laptop and it has worked with Mosaico until a recent CiviCRM upgrade and now it doesn't work/appear. Is there anything I can do to fix this or is there any other way of having a spellcheck on Mosaico? Thanks

Which browser are you using?

Google Chrome. Grammarly is working on the events section of the CRM but no longer on Mosaico.
